# Possible to hide columns in a SQL Server Management Studio database diagram?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

All of my tables have certain audit columns (CreateDate,CreateBy,UpdateDate,UpdateBy)

Since they just take up visual space, is it possible to somehow hide these columns so they do not show up in a database diagram in SSMS or SSMSE?

Comment: The best we can do is display keys only: right-click on table - Table View - Keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

You can show or hide whole tables only. Or resize. or reverse engineer into Visio or some such tool

Edit, Dec 2017

"Table View" in diagrams show **all** columns or **no** columns.
It does not remove **some** columns

Yes, you can modify the view of column **attributes** but OP did not ask this.

**Read the question please**

Comment: right click on the table and select the "Table View" and select name only

Comment: @uri The other answer this does not hide **columns**, it only hides **column attributes"

Comment: @xsl The other answer this does not hide **columns**, it only hides **column attributes"

Answer (score 8):

Actually you can. Just right click on the table and select the "Table View" from the context menu.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It's accurate going back at least to SQL2008 R2 version of SSMS.

Comment: This does not hide **columns**, it only hides **column attributes"

Comment: *select the "Table View"* -- That's not complete. It's all about what to do next. Please make this question complete, but also note gbn's comment. IMO this can never answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

You have to select all tables (ctrl+a) then select Table View > Name Only.

Comment: When i turn on **Name Only**, i still don't see a way to hide individual columns from the diagram.

Answer (score -1):

You can create views selecting only the columns you want to see in the diagram, then you use those views in the diagram instead of using the original tables.

Perhaps those views could be use by the application itself.

Comment: That doesn't include relationships.